# Combine CSS3 browser compatibility tags to one

Tags: css, cross-browser

is it possible to combine all browser compatible tags like `-webkit, -moz, -ms, -o` for one styling? So for example:

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate,
   @-moz-keyframes pulsate,
    @-ms-keyframes pulsate,
     @-o-keyframes pulsate,
         keyframes pulsate {
 from {opacity: 1 }
 to { -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); 
         -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
          -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
           -o-transform: scale(1.5);
              transform: scale(1.5);
      opacity: 0 }
}
```

If it's not. Is there any document about that to read?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. However, you can write just the unprefixed version and then use something like [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) or [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer) to add the prefixes for you. Or you can use a preprocessor. You can read a bit more about your options [in this article](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-deal-with-vendor-prefixes/).

If you do want to write everything by hand, the good news is that you don't need the `-ms-` prefix for animations. IE10 supports them unprefixed, while IE9 doesn't support them at all. So you only need to write this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes { to { -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); transform: scale(1.5); opacity: 0; } }
@-moz-keyframes { to { -moz-transform: scale(1.5); opacity: 0; } }
@-o-keyframes { to { -o-transform: scale(1.5); opacity: 0; } }
@keyframes { to { transform: scale(1.5); opacity: 0; } }
```

You don't necessarily need the `from` keyframe either. If it's missing it gets automatically generated from the default values or those already specified outside the keyframes.